# VS2015 driver package always get built

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, driver

This is only an annoying issue, but still.
I have a VS2015 driver Solutions that includes a "package" project.
This project is always getting built even when nothing happens. Probably 
something (file?) is missing but I cannot find what.

Here is the relevant part from the  Log file:

---

```
1>Target "ResolveReferences" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\Shaul\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\vJoy\2.1.6\vJoy-Master\driver\Package\Package.vcxproj" (target "Build" depends on it):

1>Done building target "ResolveReferences" in project "Package.vcxproj".
       Target "PrepareForBuild" skipped. Previously built successfully.
       Target "PrepareForBuild" skipped. Previously built successfully.

1>Target "InitializeBuildStatus" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Users\Shaul\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\vJoy\2.1.6\vJoy-Master\driver\Package\Package.vcxproj" (target "Build" depends on it):

Using "ReadLinesFromFile" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
       Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".

Using "WriteLinesToFile" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Task "WriteLinesToFile"

Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile".

Using "Touch" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Task "Touch"

Creating "Win32\Release\Package.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

Done executing task "Touch".

1>Done building target "InitializeBuildStatus" in project "Package.vcxproj".

Target "AssignProjectConfiguration" skipped. Previously built successfully.

Target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" skipped. Previously built successfully.
```

---

Comment: I suspect it's the `Touch` task that's causing the next run to detect newer files than the previous packages, causing it to rebuild. The timestamp on the files are used to detect which projects to rebuild. If all the inputs are older than the outputs, it will not rebuild. Otherwise it will.

Comment: @jessehouwing You are probably right. I have no idea where it came from and how to remove it. I suspect that is have been put there automatically.

Comment: You can share a simple projects that can reproduce that issue on the OneDrive, we will check it.

Comment: Thank you @starain. Please download the full solution that includes the package from https://github.com/shauleiz/vJoy
The project in question is 'Package' under 'Driver'

Comment: Do you build the projects/solution through BuildAll.bat or VS?

Comment: The problem arises with VS Build. BuildAll.bat is irrelevant for this case.